# Is there a way to add "clear" or "cls" to a task in ConEmu so when it opens it runs clear?

Tags: conemu

Running ConEmu with Git Bash and wondering if I can have it clear all the information when I open up the task.

Thanks.

Comment: Why you ask about ConEmu? It is your shell-related question only.

Comment: I believe there may be some confusion. I'm wondering if, regardless of my shell, can ConEmu open any shell and run a command before I even do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. That is definitely your shell responsibility to execute smth after startup.

Terminal **must not** force shell to do smth because only the shell itself can be sure that it is "ready".

At last, "proper" shells provide the ability to run smth after startup "from the box". For example

```
powershell -NoExit -Command "Write-Host 'Hello world!'"
```

Or with simplest cmd

```
cmd /k "Echo Hello world!"
```

And only bash... you need to change profile to do some automatics. That is unix way...

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I understand now and apologize for the miscommunication.